# Pivoting data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an 'articles' collection, some sample data might look like this:

```
[
{body: 'Interesting news in Siberia and so on etc. etc. etc. and lolcats too',
author: 'John Doe',
tags: [{tid:24, name: "Siberia"}, 
       {tid: 5231, name: "Lolcats"},]
},
{body: 'Something is going on in Siberia and France',
author: 'Jane Doe',
tags: [{tid:24, name: "Siberia"}, 
       {tid: 6432, name: "France"},]
},
]
```

And my required ouput is a distinct list of tags:

```
[
{tid: 24, name: 'Siberia'},
{tid: 5231, name: 'Lolcats'},
{tid: 6432, name: 'France'},
]
```

I have been struggling with some mapReduce queries and distinct aggregation, but without result.

Comment: what driver do you use? maybe just do it in your business logic

Comment: I'm using mongojs, and it most certainly could be done in the business logic. I'm just trying to as much work as possible in mongo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
db.articles.distinct("tags")
```

If you want to use aggregation framework (new in 2.2) it's a little longer:

```
db.articles.aggregate([{$unwind:"$tags"}, 
                   {$group:{_id:"$tags"}},
                   {$project:{tid:"$_id.tid",name:"$_id.name",_id:0}}
]).result
```

Answer (score 3):

In mongo v2.2 you can do this with the `aggregate` function:

```js
db.articles.aggregate([
{
    // From each document, emit just the tags
    $project: {
        tags: 1
    }
}, {
    // Duplicate each document for each tags element it contains
    $unwind: '$tags'
}, {
    // Group the documents by the tag's tid and name
    $group: {
        _id: { tid: '$tags.tid', name: '$tags.name' }
    }
}, {
    // Reshape the document to exclude the _id and bring tid and name to the top level
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        tid: '$_id.tid',
        name: '$_id.name'
    }
}],
function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('aggregation error: %s', err);
    } else {
        console.dir(result);
    }
});
```

For your documents, this produces the following output:

```
[ { tid: 6432, name: 'France' },
  { tid: 5231, name: 'Lolcats' },
  { tid: 24, name: 'Siberia' } ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
db.articles.distinct("tags")
```

gives the following output:

```
[
{
    "tid" : 24,
    "name" : "Siberia"
},
{
    "tid" : 5231,
    "name" : "Lolcats"
},
{
    "tid" : 6432,
    "name" : "France"
}
]
```